# Solve matrix equation with eigen

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

I want to solve the equation *A*B=C* for *A*, with Eigen. *A* is a (3x3) matrix, *B* and *C* are (3x25) matrices.

Currently I would compute the pseudoinverse of *B* and multiply it from right to *C*. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If found an easy solution myself: just transpose the whole equation (*B^T*A^T=C^T*) and solve it with an ordinary linear solver!

edit: it actually does not perfectly do the job, see [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418703/matrix-least-squares-with-rows-instead-of-columns)